# What is the difference between 希望（きぼう）and 気持ち（きもち）？

Tags: words, word-choice

I am new to learning the Japanese language.  I am a bit confused about the difference between 希望{きぼう} and 気持{きも}ち.

Can someone please explain the difference between them and show how to use them in a sentence?

Comment: They are entirely different words. Perhaps you could provide examples of where you faced difficulty differentiating them?

Comment: @Flaw: Thanks for the reply.But I really don't get any example related to it.Thats why I haven't quoted that out.

Comment: Perhaps include those examples that you "don't get" in the main question body?

Comment: As Flaw says, they're different words, so right now the only thing we could do to answer this question is to quote the dictionary entries for these two words (something you could look up yourself). If you give us a little more info on where you're struggling, someone can address that area specifically.

Comment: Whoever down voted this, don't do that ever. As a beginner, I know how does it feel. I also ask questions that are wrong. But there are some good guys who correct my question first explaining what the question should be and then answer. Most of the time pronunciations and meaning are vague to the beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hope" (or "wish") and "feeling" are different words.

So this is like asking, what is the difference between "apple" and "bread", and can you show this in a sentence.

(Are you sure you don't mean: what is the difference between 感じ (kanji) and 気持ち?)